# Jquery to make the if statement according the condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a problem to combine if else function in jquery, it cannot show me correct to choose the condition.

Below is my coding:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#parentid').change(function(){
         if ( $(this).val() == '0' ){
            $('#activity_code, #activity_name,#sub_activity_code,#sub_activity_name,#transaction_code,#transaction_name').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        }else{
            $('#activity_code, #activity_name').removeAttr('readonly');
        }
        if ( $(this).val() == '1' ){
            $('#function_code, #function_name,#sub_activity_code,#sub_activity_name,#transaction_code,#transaction_name').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        }else{
            $('#activity_code, #activity_name').removeAttr('readonly');
        }

        if ( $(this).val() == '2' ){
            $('#function_code, #function_name,#activity_code, #activity_name,#transaction_code,#transaction_name').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        }else{
            $('#sub_activity_code, #sub_activity_name').removeAttr('readonly');
        }

        if ( $(this).val() == '3' ){
            $('#function_code, #function_name,#activity_code, #activity_name,#sub_activity_code, #sub_activity_name').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        }else{
            $('#transaction_code,#transaction_name').removeAttr('readonly');
        }

        if ( $(this).val() == '4' ){
            $('#function_code, #function_name,#activity_code, #activity_name,#sub_activity_code, #sub_activity_name,#transaction_code,#transaction_name,#category,#request_by').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Actually I want the output show in the below, i want the output show correct what I choose the category number, below the picture will get more clear description,hope someone can guide me how to solve these problem:

[image: Output 1]

This is my html code: https://pastebin.com/N1kqzf8g

Comment: Any console error?

Comment: No. Just not according my if else statement to make the readonly

Comment: You're missing that you need to *start* with a "default" position at the top - either lock everything or unlock everything.  Then for each value add an if that locks/unlocks as required.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m answer. Can you show me the example how to lock or unlock?

Comment: Same code you already have - just one line at the top that applies to all then the individual controls in each `if`.  For "lock/unlock" I mean "readonly/available"

Comment: Sorry, I can't imagine how to write it. Can you write here?

Comment: Also, your if-else are around the wrong way - you have: if it's zero, lock inputs 2,3,4 otherwise unlock input 1 - whereas both should be inside the `if` and there shouldn't be an `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the code/complexity, you need to *reset* your inputs to their "default" position at the start, then apply as required:

Using the code you've provided, with minimal changes (added a `switch` rather than multiple if):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#parentid').change(function() {

    // Set all to readonly
    $('#activity_code,#activity_name,#activity_code,#activity_name,#sub_activity_code,#sub_activity_name,#transaction_code,#transaction_name').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

    // check each value and make relevant inputs available

    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case "0":
        $('#activity_code, #activity_name').removeAttr('readonly');
        break;

      case "1":
        $('#activity_code, #activity_name').removeAttr('readonly');
        break;

      case "2":
        $('#sub_activity_code, #sub_activity_name').removeAttr('readonly');
        break;

      case "3":
        $('#transaction_code,#transaction_name').removeAttr('readonly');
        break;

      case "4":
        // all readonly as above
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: (for "0" these should probably be "#function_" but kept the same code as in the question, concept is the same)

Comment: Can I ask you 1 more question? How to add code become can show the value in the readonly, if I have choose category number 1,2,3, the readonly can show the record

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean in your additional question.   You could add a new SO question and maybe someone else will be able to help (link here if you like).  Unless you mean `$("#id").val($(this).val())` when inside the `select` change event.